# Linux command to connect to a Bluetooth device

Tags: linux, networking, bluetooth

I have this Pi project where DBUS is not an option, but bluetooth connections are needed, in an embedded-like enviroment where services are mostly unwanted.

I was able to setup the BT hardware on the Pi by loading it's modules, and attaching it to hci:

```
sudo modprobe hci_uart
sudo modprobe btbcm
sudo hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -
```

I can see it's working without problems with:

```
sudo hciconfig -a
```

I can easily bring up the device like this:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

I can even scan devices with `sudo hcitool scan`, and I can see the target devices in range. Great so far!

The problem comes when I try to connect the Pi3b+ to them. There used to be `hidd --connect <address>`, but the hidd command has been deprecated in favor of some mumbo-jumbo using DBUS and systemd services. I guess a service is needed to manage connections, etc, but all I need here is to manually stablish an one-time BT connection manually. Simple.

So, what should I use in place of `hidd --connect <address>` now? I have tried `sudo hcitool cc <address>`, but it doesn't stablish any connections (connections can be verified with hcitool con).

Please don't tell me to use the bluetoothd service, that's not an option.